# How to be sure that Assembly.LoadFrom really loads a DLL file in?

Tags: c#, .net, dll, assemblies

I'm trying to add my plugins to my application via Assembly.LoadFrom and I would like to know if there's a property to know what type of assembly was loaded - dynamically linked library and executables can be loaded, right?

Thank you!

Comment: Not sure I understand the question - unless *executed*, an exe containing an assembly is still just an assembly package. Can't you just use `Path.GetExtension()` here?

Comment: Agreed.  Who cares what the filename extension is?  Managed code is a bit unusual that way compared to unmanaged code.  But that's a flaw in unmanaged code.  Code == code, whatever name is on the wrapper.  Feature, not a bug.

Comment: This is kind of off topic, but I would recommend to you taking a look at MEF because it is a (imo) great and easy to use framework for adding plugin functionality to your application.

Comment: @Oliver: I'm aware of MEF but my plugin system is working now and the deadline is very near. My program is in .NET 3.5 and MEF targets .NET 4, am I right? I will definitely look at it in future.

Comment: I see. Btw, on Codeplex there are binaries of MEF for .NET 3.5 (http://mef.codeplex.com/).

Comment: Yeah, but it seems to be a preview.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can determine whether the Assembly returned by the LoadFrom function has loaded an EXE or DLL using the Assembly.EntryPoint property. If the property returns a MethodInfo for the entry point function, then you are dealing with an EXE.

From MSDN:

> Type:
>   System.Reflection.MethodInfo An object
>   that represents the entry point of
>   this assembly. If no entry point is
>   found (for example, the assembly is a
>   DLL), null is returned.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.entrypoint.aspx

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know if it was a .exe or a .dll, you can check [Assembly.Location](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.location.aspx).